# How can I convert SQL Server data to importable goinstant data?

Tags: goinstant

I'm looking for a way to import a SQL Server table data into goinstant. Is there a JSON editor or script that allows this and that can be clipboard pasted right into goinstant?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not anything officially supported by GoInstant that can help convert your relational database into a key value store at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I may have come up with a solution.  I was able to use a previously created sql to json object tsql script written by Matthew D. Erwin. I modified it to handle creating an importable output to goinstant.  See the script [here](https://github.com/magazinebrute/goinstant/blob/master/Sql-data-to-goinstant-stored-procedure.txt) on github, or feel free to grab it from below.

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetJSON]    Script Date: 5/16/2014 9:04:40 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

--
-- Author:      Matthew D. Erwin (Snaptech, LLC)
-- Create date: May 9, 2013    
-- Modified date: May 16, 2014 by Rudy E. Hinojosa (CBM Archives, LLC) rudy.hinojosa@cbmarchives.com                                            
-- Description: Returns the contents of a given table                      
--              in JavaScript Object Notation JSON - 
--
--              Very notably useful for generating MOCK .json files
--              for testing or before RESTful services are completed.
--
--              This implementation:
--                  *removed cursor (using FOR XML PATH(''))
--                  *properly supports NULL vs quoted values
--                  *supports dates in ISO 8601 - presuming UTC
--                  *uses Data_Type and Is_Nullable info
--                  *escapes '\'
--                  *formats output with tabs/newlines
--                  *can return final results as XML to bypass
--                   truncation in SSMS
--                  *supports schema (e.g. [dbo].[TableName]
--                  *includes "recordCount" field
-- Options:                                                                
--      @table_name: the table to execute the query                        
--      @limit: equivalent to "select top N * from table" 
--      @ssms: flag to use if executing in Sql Server Management Studio
--             to bypass result truncation limits.
--      @isgoinstant: flag to use if importing results to GoInstant database
-- 
-- Inspired primarily by the 2008 work of Thiago R. Santos which was influenced by Thomas Frank.
-- Usage: [dbo].[GetJSON] @Table_name = 'MySchema.MyTable', @limit = 50, @ssms = 0, @isgoinstant = 0

CREATE procedure [dbo].[GetJSON] (
    @table_name varchar(max), 
    @limit int = null,
    @ssms bit = 0,
    @isgoinstant bit = 0
)
as
begin
        declare @json varchar(max), @query varchar(max), @table_schema varchar(max) = null
if( charindex('.', @table_name) > 0 )
begin
    set @table_schema = replace(replace( substring(@table_name, 0, charindex('.',@table_name)), '[', ''), ']', '')
    set @table_name = replace(replace( substring(@table_name, charindex('.',@table_name) + 1,len(@table_name)), '[', ''), ']', '')
end

set @query = 
    'select ' + case when @limit is not null then 'top ' + cast(@limit as varchar(32)) + ' ' else '' end + ''' '' + REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(''' +
    --case when @isgoinstant is not null then ('"' + cast(newid() as varchar(max)) + '"' + ': { ') else '' end +
    CAST((SELECT ' "' + column_name + '" : ' + 
        case when is_nullable = 'YES' 
            then ''' + case when [' + column_name + '] is null then ''null'' else ' + 
                case when data_type like '%binar%' then null else '' end +
                case when data_type like 'XM%' then null else '' end +
                case when data_type like '%char%' or data_type like '%text%' then '''"'' + ' else '' end + 
                case when data_type like '%date%' then 'char(34) + convert(varchar(23),[' + column_name + '], 126) + ''Z'' + char(34)' else 
                'replace(replace(replace(replace(cast([' + column_name + '] as varchar(max)),''\'',''\\''),''"'',''\"''),char(10),''\n''),char(13),''\n'') ' end + 
                case when data_type like '%char%' or data_type like '%text%' then '+ ''"''' else '' end + ' end + ''' 
            else 
                case when data_type like '%binar%' then null else '' end +
                case when data_type like 'XM%' then null else '' end +
                case when data_type like '%char%' or data_type like '%text%' then '"' else '' end + 
                ''' + ' +
                case when data_type like '%date%' then 'char(34) + convert(varchar(23),[' + column_name + '], 126) + ''Z + char(34)' else 
                'replace(replace(replace(replace(cast([' + column_name + '] as varchar(max)),''\'',''\\''),''"'',''\"''),char(10),''\n''),char(13),''\n'') + ''' end +
                case when data_type like '%char%' or data_type like '%text%' then '"' else '' end end + ',' AS [text()] 
                from information_schema.columns where table_name = @table_name and (@table_schema is null or table_schema = @table_schema) FOR XML PATH('') ) as varchar(max)) +
                '''),1,1,'''')) + '' }'' as json into tmpJsonTable from ' + @table_name + ' with(nolock) '
exec sp_sqlexec @query

if (@isgoinstant = 0)
set @json = 
    '{' + char(10) + char(9) +
    '"recordCount" : ' + Cast((select count(*) from tmpJsonTable) as varchar(32)) + ',' + char(10) + char(9) +
    '"records" : ' + char(10) + char(9) + char(9) + '[' + char(10)
    + REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(CAST((SELECT char(9) + char(9) + json + ',' + char(10) AS [text()] FROM tmpJsonTable FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar(max))),1,2,''))
    + char(10) + char(9) + char(9) + ']' + char(10) + '}'
else
    set @json = 
    '{' + char(10) + char(9) +
    REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(CAST((SELECT case when @isgoinstant is not null then ('"' + cast(newid() as varchar(max)) + '"' + ': { ') else '' end + char(9) + json + ',' + char(10) AS [text()] FROM tmpJsonTable FOR XML PATH('')) AS varchar(max))),1,2,''))
    + char(10) + char(9) + char(9) + '}'



drop table tmpJsonTable
if( @ssms = 1 and len(@json) > 65535 ) --deal with Sql Server Management Studio text/grid truncation
    select cast('<json><![CDATA[' + @json + ']]></json>' as xml) as jsonString
else
    select @json as jsonString
end
GO
```